# Is right way to use thread for getting data from server and updating list view

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i m new android and find the best approach to update the data on UI with thread-safety for getting data from server.
here is my code to get data from server api and update list view,
but i was think this approach may cause to degrade the performance of application.
i m using okhttp for calling server api.

```
public String ActionAsyncGetTeamData(final String URL, final String token,final String expected_closure_date, final HTTPVerb verb, Activity activity) {
    final String[] ResponseData = new String[1];
    loading_complete=false;
    _context = activity;

    if (networkDetector.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ResponseData[0] = GET(URL, token, expected_closure_date);
                leadList.clear();
                meetingList.clear();
                taskList.clear();

                TeamSyncModel teamSyncModel=json.fromJson(ResponseData[0],TeamSyncModel.class);
                for (LeadModel leadModel: teamSyncModel.lead) {
                    leadList.add(leadModel);
                }
                for (MeetingModel meetingModel: teamSyncModel.meeting) {
                    meetingList.add(meetingModel);
                }
                for (TaskModel taskModel: teamSyncModel.task) {
                    taskList.add(taskModel);
                }
                loading_complete=true;

                _context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Planner planner=new Planner();
                        planner.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        planner.list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        planner.adapterTeam(_context);
                        planner.closure_header.requestFocus();
                    }
                });


            }
        }).start();
        return ResponseData[0];
    }
    else {
        Planner planner=new Planner();
        planner.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        planner.list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        planner.adapterTeam(_context);
        leadList.clear();
        meetingList.clear();
        taskList.clear();
        loading_complete=true;
        Toast.makeText(_context.getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Get data from Server

```
private String GET(String url, String token, String lastSync) {
    client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url + lastSync)
                .addHeader("x-access-token", token)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

is it right way to do this tasks in android

Comment: Use AsyncTask. Also didn't write ugly codes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try the following steps

```
1 in UI create refer to listview, adapter and asyntask
2 from the ui send reference to adapter at the asyntask in this getData from server and in the method onPostExecute of the asynk call this method adapter.notifyDatasetChange();
3 in the adapter you manage the info what you give of the server in the asyntask
```